# (complex variables)Calculate the integrals below using the theory seen on Cauchy's integral formula....

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification, problem-solving, complex-integration

> Calculate the integrals below using the theory seen on Cauchy's integral formula. Do not use the formula that involves parameterization to $\gamma$ when the path is of class $C^1$ ny parts.

> a)$\int_{\gamma} \frac{log z}{z^n}dz$, where $\gamma(t) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}e^{it}, 0 \le t \le 2\pi$ e $n \in \mathbb N$.

> b)$\int_{\gamma} \frac{z^2 + 1}{z(z^2 + 9)}dz$, where $\gamma(t) = re^{it}, 0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi$, and $0 \lt r$ and $r \ne 3$.

a)Let $a =0, n=n,f(z)=log z$

$f'(1)= \frac{1}{zln10}$

$f^{(2)}= - \frac{1}{z^2 ln 10}$

$f^{(3)}= \frac{2}{z^3 ln 10}$

$f^{(4)}= - \frac{6}{z^4 ln 10}$

$f^{(5)}=  \frac{24}{z^5 ln 10}$

$f^{(6)}= - \frac{120}{z^5 ln 10}$

$f^{(7)}=  \frac{720}{z^5 ln 10}$

$f^{(n)}=  (-1)^{(n+1)}\frac{(n-1)!}{z^5 ln 10} = \frac{n!}{2 \pi i} \int\frac{log z}{(z-0)^n} = (-1)^{(n+1)}\frac{2 \pi i}{z^5 ln 10 n} = \int\frac{log z}{(z-0)^n}$

b)

I think there's something missing for item a) but I'm not quite sure what. As for b) I'm kind of lost, would partial fractions work? seems quite complicated.

Comment: The integrand in the first integral is holomorphic in the domain bounded by $\gamma$. What does this imply for the integral? For the second integral, you will need to calculate residues at the poles of the integrand. The easiest way would be to use partial fractions first, but you could find the residues directly.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{z^2+1}{z(z^2+9)}=\frac{1/9}{z}+\frac{4/9}{z+3i}+\frac{4/9}{z-3i}$, we get that $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^2+1}{z(z^2+9)}dz=\int_{\gamma}\frac{1/9}{z}dz+\int_{\gamma}\frac{4/9}{z+3i}dz+\int_{\gamma}\frac{4/9}{z-3i}dz$$
Applying the cauchy's integral formula we obtain that

$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^2+1}{z(z^2+9)}dz=\begin{cases}
\frac{2\pi i}{9} &  0<r<3 \\
2\pi i & {r>3} 
\end{cases}$$

Note that using residues theorem is easier. Since the poles of the function are $z=0,z=\pm 3i$, which are all simple, we need to differenciate two cases.

**If $0<r<3$**

The onlye pole contained in the interior of our contour is $z=0$ so just applying the residues theorem we get
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^2+1}{z(z^2+9)}dz=2\pi i Res(f,0)=2\pi i \lim_{z\to 0}z\frac{z^2+1}{z(z^2+9)}=2\pi i \frac{1}{9}=\frac{2\pi i}{9}$$

**If $3<r$**

Now all the poles are contained in the interior of the contour so we just apply the residues theorem to all of them:

$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^2+1}{z(z^2+9)}dz=2\pi i (Res(f,0)+Res(f,3i)+Res(f,-3i))=2\pi i$$